# How to show hide content inside divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code here which is working but I want to display one div at a time.

The link to my codepen is here:

https://codepen.io/danongu/pen/YzXvpoJ

I did not post the entire code here because it has a lot of html and CSS. I am having trouble with the js part.

What I'm hoping to achieve:

When you click the `Section A Book List` button, you should see just the `PREVIOUS VERSIONS A` and `NEW VERSIONS A` part.

Clicking the `Section B Book List` button, you should see just the `PREVIOUS VERSIONS B` and `NEW VERSIONS B` part.

For the `Book 1` and `Book 2` black area. I am hoping to show the `BOOK 1` part when you click the `Book 1` and `BOOK 2` when you click `Book 2`

So some kind of conditional show/hide thing going on there. I tried to write some jquery but I couldn't go further than the attempt in the codepen.

Please take a look. I gave a small attempt but got stuck along the way.

Comment: Click the "console" button at the bottom left (or use the real browser console) and you'll see "ReferenceError: $ is not defined".  Looks like you forgot to include jquery itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a class or better an id to each section book list wrapper, e.g.

```html
<div id="bbl-wrapper1">
  <button class="toggle1">Section A Book List </button>
  <button class="toggle2">Section B Book List </button>

  <div class="clearfix" id="section-a">...</div>

  <div class="clearfix" id="section-b">...</div>
</div>
```

And then hide the `#section-b` by default:

```css
#section-b {
  display: none;
}
```

And then wire things with jQuery like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $secA = $("#section-a");
  var $secB = $("#section-b");

  $('.toggle1').click(function() {
    $secA.show();
    $secB.hide();
  });

  $('.toggle2').click(function() {
    $secA.hide();
    $secB.show();
  });
});
```

You can apply the same logic to the `BOOK 1` and `BOOK2`.

P.S. the id `bbl` occurs twice in your html. The value of `id` must be unique for each element.

Comment: @maryongubo you seem to have changed your code version from yesterday. :)
I tested it yesterday, and it worked. So, I don't know what you are trying to achieve in your actual version... But the logic remains same. If you understood my sample code above, you can apply it to views with any number of tabs.